# How to send an sms comfirmation for when user sign up

Tags: php, sms

I'm creating a website that requires user to sign up in order to get an account.I was just wondering, what type of api/code/etc do I need to use to send a verification code to directly to their phones.Once they receive the message they should be able to send like a text to that number (ex: send yes to confirm to the number #987) and the account automatically gets confirm from the text message.

Comment: There are api's out there to accomplish this...I would use `google` to help you find them.  It will probably cost you money to use the api's.

Comment: Try twilio maybe: https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install The same code on that page has worked for me in the past. You would still need to pay for outgoing (and possibly incoming) SMS messages as @brso05 mentioned.

Comment: i am looking for something for free the website will have a lot of users

Comment: I think most of the SMS APIs will be paid or the free versions will have restrictions. If you don't need the SMS verification absolutely then you can do the verification via email as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you've got a list of SMS APIs: http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-50-sms-apis/. It's from 2013 though, some of them might have changed. You do have free APIs like http://textbelt.com/ but it depends on where do you want to send those SMSem, different providers in different countries have different gateways. I think it's impossible to answer you in 1 sentence.